# Can a fan blowing on you at night make you sick?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

It has been pretty hot in my neck of the woods over the last week.  It has been roughly 80 degrees in my room at night.  To try to stay comfortable and get to sleep I have been running two fans.  One in the window and one pointed at my bed.  Today I woke up with a headache, runny nose, and sore throat.  Someone was telling me that if you have a fan blowing on you at night it will make you sick.  It seems a [common](http://ilovefreeenergy.info/water-power/could-i-have-gotten-sick-from-the-fan-blowing-in-my-face/) [meme](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_catch_a_cold_by_sleeping_with_a_fan_on) [on the](http://www.chacha.com/question/can-you-get-sick-from-a-fan-when-your-sleeping) [internet](http://voices.yahoo.com/does-sleeping-fan-sick-1460677.html)  Is that true?

Comment: Related:  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/548/can-you-die-if-you-leave-a-fan-running-in-a-closed-room?rq=1  and http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/617/can-using-an-air-conditioner-while-sleeping-be-harmful?lq=1

Comment: I think this is different.  We are talking about air blowing at you, not just being on in the room.  Much more likely to have a real effect

Comment: @Brightblades, neither of those questions are like what I am asking.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics, we require questions here to be about notable claims that are held to be true by a significant number of people. We have already two related questions on the site, but if you can show the notability of your third, different claim this question could be reopened.

Comment: I said _related_ because if you look at the answers, some do indeed talk about other effects of fans and air conditioning going in a room (i.e. dry air and such).  :)

Comment: This is a pretty common meme.  I added some links for notablity

Comment: Is this a dupe of this question? http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/88/cold-and-catching-colds-temperature-and-disease

Comment: @SamIAm - I do not think so but I think it is probably related.

Comment: These are all symptoms of dust mite allergies as well - if the fan is blowing dust all over, then it could be an allergic reaction.  You may not normally be reactive to dust mites, but then you don't normally have a fan blowing them into you face all night either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is inconclusive evidence.**

The Cochrane Review found there is inconclusive evidence to support whether or not electric fans may cause an adverse effect on one’s health<sup>1</sup>.

**Citation**

<sup>1</sup>[Electric fans for reducing adverse health impacts in heatwaves](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22786530)

Comment: +1: I love that there was a Cochrane Review on this. It never occurred to me for a second to look there.